# How to save the word document location manually every time when we run the code in python

Tags: python, python-docx

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_picture('log.jpg')
doc.save('test.docx')
```

/*For this above code it saves a file as test in particular location, but i need to save the file in different location every time i run the code with different name.
Ex: 1st time running code- save in Desktop as Des1.docx
2nd time running code- Save in Document folder as Documnet1.docx
Is it possible to save the word document where ever we want in python using docx.*/

Comment: You can do that by adding random generation of names and appending the path to one of the predefined list

Comment: You can use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) to find a filename that doesn't exist yet in the most secure way possible. It's not just for temporary files.